# Infinity loop while reading data from file

Tags: c, iostream

I'm trying to read data from file. There are three rows. What I've done is this below. Problem is that (file exists) it is infinity loop while reading a file. I've observed that program is not moving line by line until it reaches end of file. What's incorrect in my code?

CODE:

```
if (desktops == NULL) {
        printf("\n No such file.\n");
    } else{
            printf("\nFile exists. Reading\n");

        while(!feof(desktops)){

            if(numberOfObjects== 0)
            {
                 fscanf(desktops,"%fl %fl %fl %fl %d %s %s %d\n",&height,&length,&width,&processorClock,&idNumberSerial,&processorTypeChars,&nameInNetworkChars,&ID);
                 nameInNetwork = string(nameInNetworkChars);
                 processorType = string(processorTypeChars);
                // nameInNetwork = "test";
                 glowaListyObjektow = new Desktop(height,length,width,processorClock,idNumberSerial,processorType,nameInNetwork,ID);
                 iterator = glowaListyObjektow;


                 iterator->previousObject = NULL;
                 iloscObiektow++;
                 nameInNetwork.clear();
                 processorType.clear();
            }
            else if(numberOfObjects> 0)
            {
                fscanf(desktops,"%fl %fl %fl %fl %d %s %s %d\n",&height,&length,&width,&processorClock,&idNumberSerial,&processorTypeChars,&nameInNetworkChars,&ID);
                nameInNetwork = string(nameInNetworkChars);
                processorType = string(processorTypeChars);
                // nameInNetwork = "test";
                iterator->nextObject = new Desktop(height,length,width,processorClock,idNumberSerial,processorType,nameInNetwork,ID);


                iterator->nextObject->previousObject = iterator;
                iterator = iterator->nextObject;
                iloscObiektow++;
                 nameInNetwork.clear();
                 processorType.clear();
                // nameInNetworkChars = NULL;
            }



            cout<<"reading line"<<endl;
// Here line above is printed infinitely.
        }
            fclose(desktops);
    }
```

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems that I see.

1. You are using the wrong format, `%fl` instead of `%lf`.
2. You are not checking whether `fscanf` successfully read the data or not.

Change

```
 fscanf(desktops,"%fl %fl %fl %fl %d %s %s %d\n", &height, &length, &width, &processorClock, &idNumberSerial, &processorTypeChars, &nameInNetworkChars, &ID);
```

to

```
 int n = fscanf(desktops,"%lf %lf %lf %lf %d %s %s %d\n", &height, &length, &width, &processorClock, &idNumberSerial, &processorTypeChars, &nameInNetworkChars, &ID);
 if ( n != 8 )
 {
    // Deal with error condition
 }
```